# Trying to create a cookie to track users in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to check if the cookie "VIS" exists using `$_COOKIE[]` but returning syntax error: `FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or heredoc end (T_END_HEREDOC) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) on line number 22`. I was wondering if anyone could help me. Thanks!

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['VIS'])) {
    echo <<<_END
    <script>
        var au_prompt = window.prompt("Already been used here.\nEnter AU Command:");
        switch (au_prompt) {
            case "conL":
                break;
            case "doA":
                window.alert("Done.");
                window.close();
                break;
            default:
                window.alert("Incorrect code.");
                window.close();
                break;
        }
    </script>
    _END;
} else {
    setcookie("VIS", 1, time() + (10000 * 100000));
}
```

Comment: There must be absolutely no whitespace on the line before the ending Heredoc token.

Comment: Yes no whitespace, but also not on the same line with the last line. Try removing the four spaces or tab before _END; and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the [PHP Documents](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for heredoc

> **Warning**
>   It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You can always close the PHP tags.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['VIS'])) {
    ?>
    <script>
        var au_prompt = window.prompt("Already been used here.\nEnter AU Command:");
        switch (au_prompt) {
            case "conL":
                break;
            case "doA":
                window.alert("Done.");
                window.close();
                break;
            default:
                window.alert("Incorrect code.");
                window.close();
                break;
        }
    </script>
    <?php
} else {
    setcookie("VIS", 1, time() + (10000 * 100000));
}
?>
```